# NullPointerException when calling TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()

Tags: java, timezone, nullpointerexception

I tried many examples of code where i do basically

```
String[] IDs = java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();
```

and it doesn't work.
I've also tried another frame of example code, i.e. [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/timezone_getavailableid_offset.htm) and it returns:

```
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.getZoneIDs(ZoneInfoFile.java:785)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getAvailableIDs(ZoneInfo.java:560)
at java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.java:508)
at TimeZoneDemo.main(uu.java:6)
```

I tried also to reinstall the JRE and JDK, but the error persists. So what's the point?
When I try to do `String[] eg = {"one","two"};` it works.

Comment: That shouldn't happen, sounds like something is screwed up with the tz zoneinfo files. How are you invoking the java process?

Comment: yes, i compiled first with javac and after run with java <name class> and it returned this exception.

Comment: Can you post the complete exception? Also, is the posted exception the one you get from your example or the linked one from tutorialspoint.com? Can you post your complete example code?

Comment: Also confirm if you have $JAVA_HOME environment variable set to same place you expect JDK or JRE to be ?  or anything that might make it look in the wrong place for zoneinfo data.  Files are usually in $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/zi/**  (the jre/ part maybe optional if all you have is JRE not JDK)

Comment: Without a COMPLETE stacktrace we're all shooting in the dark.

Comment: @Simon the complete exception is that i've posted and the example code is very similiar to this.

Comment: @DarrylMiles  $JAVA_HOME is unset and in the path /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/zi there's nothing.

Comment: @Jim Garrison The stack trace above is just complete.

Comment: What linux distro?  did you include all suggested packages (when you installed the JRE/JDK from the package manager).  Hint: many distros package up the zoneinfo as a separate package so it can be updated independently of the main JRE/JDK (because some countries change their DST switchover date each year).  On CentOS I have package "tzdata-java.noarch" but other distos have different package name.  Try downloading JDK from Sun/Oracle site see if problem goes away.  Then lookup your distos tzdata package name and ensure it is installed.

Comment: The distro is Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS. I've many files related tzdata in /var/lib/dpkg/info for example /var/lib/dpkg/info/tzdata-java.list. I pasted here the complete search for 'tzdata' http://pastebin.com/qtL7F6AZ . I controlled the packages installed and i've tzdata and tzdata-java.

Comment: i resolved. There were also openjdk-6-xx packages. I removed it, done the update and now works. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll find the same problem here:

- http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/532341/
- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/FE-2662
- https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6529213

SUGGESTION:

Download and run the latest tzupdater tool, and see if it resolves the problem:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tzupdater-readme-136440.html

Comment: As i said above, when i try to do ./tzupdater.jar --update it returns **can't read ZoneInfoMappings at /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/zi** and in that folder there's nothing.

Answer (score 17):

Try this if you are using Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:justinludwig/tzdata
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tzdata-java
```

Comment: Thanks, @Gavy. Worked for me. For more context, see http://blog.swwomm.com/2016/05/ubuntu-1604-with-java-7-timezone-data.html -- I had to `sudo apt-get update` in between the two lines above.

Comment: If it's working for you, please accept my answer and up vote. Thanks!

Comment: I've upvoted it, but can't accept it as the answer because i'm not OP.

Comment: I can confirm this working on Ubuntu Xenial 16.04 and OpenJDK 7.  (OpenJDK 8 doesn't need this, as the timezone data is already included in the package).

Comment: Thanks @Gavy, It's the only solution work on UBUNTU 16.04 ,