# Ganib (Java) - unable to send verification email

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a VPS server running on Ubuntu 16.04. Ganib software (Java) is being run by Tomcat. While trying to register I get a very poor log:

```
=========== checking limit ==========
Payment plan property toke not enaled
Is Valid 1
DEBUG: JavaMail version 1.4.4
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.providers
DEBUG: Tables of loaded providers
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Class Name: {com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport=javax.mail.Provider[TRANSPORT,smtps,com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSSLTransport,Sun Microsystems, Inc], com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport=javax.ma$
DEBUG: Providers Listed By Protocol: {imaps=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc], imap=javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystem$
DEBUG: successfully loaded resource: /META-INF/javamail.default.address.map
Exception while sending mail: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

This is my config.xml file in tomcat:

```
<Resource name="mail/GanibSession"
auth="Container"
type="javax.mail.Session"
mail.smtp.host="smtp.gmail.com"
mail.smtp.port="465"
mail.smtp.auth="true"
mail.smtp.user="xxx@gmail.com"
password="xxx"
mail.smtp.starttls.enable="true"
mail.debug="true"
mail.smtp.socketFactory.class="javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory"
/>
```

How do I even debug this? I'm not familiar with Java.

edit: Just found a stack trace!

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile.getZoneIDs(ZoneInfoFile.java:790)
at sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo.getAvailableIDs(ZoneInfo.java:601)
at java.util.TimeZone.getAvailableIDs(TimeZone.java:586)
at org.apache.jsp.newregistration.registerUserProcessing_jsp._jspService(registerUserProcessing_jsp.java:398)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
... omitted for brevity
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding a stack trace (which was by the way found in network tab of developer tools and then in response tab) I found an answer in this thread:

[NullPointerException when calling TimeZone.getAvailableIDs()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12414775/nullpointerexception-when-calling-timezone-getavailableids)

I stopped tomcat, ran these commands and then started it again:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:justinludwig/tzdata
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tzdata-java
```